# Couldn't boot to Pop OS!

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, pop-os

I'm new to linux community and wanted to try Pop OS! I followed every instruction exactly as it was listed, but I still couldn't boot to the OS. I was able to install Ubuntu without any problem using the same process as mentioned in Pop OS!

After the USB drive was flashed to make bootable using Etcher, I checked on Device Manager/Disk Management in Windows 10, I see unallocated space. Not sure if this means anything. However, when I put in the USB on Ubuntu, it showed all the files from Pop OS ISO.

My Secure boot is disabled and made sure that I boot from USB flash drive. It goes to the blank screen and stops!

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?